# NetworkX how to read nodes and edges from file

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I want to read a file with nodes and edges, in order to pass the following info:

1. The weight of each edge
2. Department_id of each node (if department_id > 0, colorize the node with a specific color, else fill it black)

Here is the file structure:

```
graph [      
      node [
        id 1
        label "Node 1"
        department_id 1
      ]
      node [
        id 2
        label "Node 2"
        department_id 0
      ]
      node [
        id 3
        label "Node 3"
        department_id 2
      ]
      edge [
        source 1
        target 2
        weight 7
      ]
      edge [
        source 1
        target 3
        weight 3
      ]
      edge [
        source 2
        target 3
        weight 1
      ]
]
```

And here is my simple code to read the file and draw the network:

```
def gml_file_importer(self):
        self.G = nx.read_gml(self.gml_file)
        print "GML file %s was successfully imported" %self.gml_file

def draw_network(self):
        nx.draw(self.G, node_size=30)
        plt.savefig("graph")
```

Can you help me a little bit to read the file and do what i describe?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your example file needs to have the top-level "graph []" declaration to be valid gml.  E.g.

```
graph [
  node [
    id 1
    label "Node 1"
    dapartment id 1
  ]
  ...
]
```

Once I add that the file imports into networkx fine.

This will draw graph `G`, colouring nodes green or black and adding labels.

```
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, 
  nodelist=[n for n in G.node if G.node[n]['department_id'] > 0], node_color='g')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, 
  nodelist=[n for n in G.node if G.node[n]['department_id'] <= 0], node_color='black')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, 
  {(frm, to): G.edge[frm][to]['weight'] for (frm, to) in G.edges()})
```

Comment: Thank you! It works much better! Can i adjust edge weight (width) instead of edge_labels? for example i tried: `nx.draw_networkx_edges(self.G, pos, {(frm, to): self.G.edge[frm][to]['weight'] for (frm, to) in self.G.edges()}, width=float({(frm, to): self.G.edge[frm][to]['weight'] for (frm, to) in self.G.edges()}))`  but it doesnt work

Comment: I solve it! `nx.draw_networkx_edges(self.G, pos, width = [self.G.edge[frm][to]['weight'] for (frm, to) in self.G.edges()])`